# how to get name of file that trigger lambda from s3 in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sftp

Tell me how can I get the file name that trigger lambda from s3 inside lambda code in java?
My task is to copy a file from s3 which goes there to my sftp server use lambda. In order for me not to copy every time all the files from the folder, I need to find out which file calling lambda.

P.S. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Sample event that is sent to Lambda is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html#test-manual-invoke).

We can use [java-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-samples.html) jar, will give us `S3Event` class with exact schema.

We need to loop on records and find `s3.object.key`:

```
package com.test;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event;

public class MyHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(S3Event request, Context context) {
        request.getRecords().forEach(record -> {
            System.out.println(record.getS3().getObject().getKey());
        });
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Comment: @Sasha Great! If this answered your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/919289) the answer, so, its helpful to spot.